# proper useragent for scraping LinkedIn profile page data

Tags: python, python-3.x, linkedin-api, screen-scraping

I have been trying to scrape data from my `linkedIn` public profile page with the code given below. I tried many possible `useragent` strings, and lastly even got a result with ua: [Googlebot/2.1](http://www.google.com/bot.html).
Still I am continueosly getting the same error:

> raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
>   urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 999: Request denied

code:

```
import urllib.request
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from http.cookiejar import CookieJar
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url="https://www.linkedin.com/in/satadal-chakravarty-4616b194/?locale=de_DE"
ua = UserAgent()
req = urllib.request.Request(url)
cj = CookieJar()
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)')]
response = opener.open(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.read().decode('utf-8'), "html5lib")
print(soup.prettify())
print("\n\n\n\n", soup.title)
```

Kindly suggest what am i doing wrong.
Also if there are any other suitable `UserAgents` for this task?

Comment: LinkedIn has blocked your scraping i.e. it knows you're using a bot

Comment: LinkedIn may have blocked your IP as well. LinkedIn has lot of scraping protection even for the public non authenticated pages

Comment: so how to surpass this??

Comment: has someone done this before???can it be done now???
I have tried many useragent strings from [here](https://deviceatlas.com/blog/list-of-web-crawlers-user-agents)